# Find a complex function, given the imaginary part of its derivative and its values at two points

Tags: complex-analysis

It is given that $\operatorname{Im}(f'(z))=6x(2y-1)$ and $f(0)=3-2i$, $f(1)=6-5i$ then what is the value of $f(1+i)=?$.

I tried by  assuming $f(z)=u+iv$ and $z=x+iy$ so $\operatorname{Im}f'(z)=v'=6x(2y-1)$ but couldn't reach to a profitable conclusion.

Any help or hint please.

**Edit** Using C-R equation I got $f'(z)=6x^2+6y-6y^2+i(12xy-6x)$

But don't how to find the antiderivative.

Also found that this is a duplicate of [this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342738/find-f1i-if-imfz-6x2x-y-f0-3-2i-f1-6-5i)

Comment: In general $\text{Im}f'(z)=v'$ is not true.

Comment: Then what way I should proceed? @NikitaEvseev

Comment: 1. Use Cauchy-Riemann equations to find $\text{Re} f'(z)$. 2. Find anti-derivative $f(z).$

Comment: Tried that but I am confused with that.

Comment: @NikitaEvseev in order to do (use CR) that it should be added to the assumptions that $f$ is holomorphic. This has not been said by now.

Comment: can you suggest something after my edit? @Thomas

Comment: @Thomas, $V(x,y) = 6x(2y-1)$ is a harmonic function and we can find another harmonic function $U(x,y)$ s. t. $F = U + iV$ is holomorphic, and $\operatorname{Im}(F'(z)) = \operatorname{Im}(f'(z))=6x(2y-1)$. So I think, from the very beginning we could consider $f'$ as holomorphic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to differentiate the givens.

If $f=u+iv$ is an analytic function of $z=x+iy$ then
$$f'(z)=\lim_{\Delta z\to0}{f(z+\Delta z)-f(z)\over\Delta z}=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}{f(z+\Delta x)-f(z)\over\Delta x}=u_x+ iv_x\ .$$We are given that
$$-u_y=v_x={\rm Im}\bigl(f'(z)\bigr)=12 xy-6x\ .$$
It follows that
$$\eqalign{u(x,y)&=-6xy^2+6xy+p(x) \cr
v(x,y)&=6x^2 y-3x^2+q(y)\cr}$$
with real valued functions $p$ and $q$ depending only on the indicated variable. From this we deduce
$$u_x=-6y^2+6y+p'(x) ,\qquad
v_y=6x^2 +q'(y)\ .$$
As the left sides of these equations coincide this enforces
$$p'(x)-6x^2=q'(y)+6y^2-6y=c\ ,$$
whereby the real constant $c$ comes from the fact that the variables on the left are "separated". We therefore obtain
$$p(x)=2x^3+cx+a,\qquad q(y)=-2y^3+3y^2+cy+b$$
for certain real constants $a$ and $b$. This leads to
$$\eqalign{f(z)&=2x^3-6xy^2 +6xy+cx+a+i(-2y^3+6x^2 y+3y^2-3x^2+cy+b)\cr &=2z^3-3i z^2+cz +a+ib\ .\cr}$$
The condition $f(0)=3-2i$ determines $a+ib=3-2i$. Since we also want $f(1)=6-5i$ we obtain the condition
$$6-5i=2-3i+c+3-2i$$
which leads to the admissible value $c=1$. One now easily obtains $f(1+i)=6+3i$.

Answer (score 1):

1. Let $f'(z) = U(z) + iV(z)$. Cauchy-Riemann equations are
   $$
   \begin{cases}U'_x=V'_y,\\ U'_y=-V'_x.\end{cases}
   $$
   We know $V = 6x(2y-1)$. It follows 
   $$
   \begin{cases}U'_x=12x,\\ U'_y=-6(2y-1).\end{cases}
   $$
   From the second equation $U(x,y) = -6y^2 +6y + C(x)$. Then substituting $U$ to the first equation we achieve $U(x,y)=-6y^2+6y + 6x^2 + C$ and
   $$
   f'(z) = -6y^2+6y + 6x^2 + i6x(2y-1) + C,
   $$ 
   where $C$ is some constant. Note, that $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C$.
2. Now integrate $f'(z)$ to find $f(z)$:
   $$
   f(z) = f(0) + \int\limits_{[0,z]}f'(z)\, dz.
   $$

Then use value $f(1)$ to rid of constant.

3. Alternatively we could note 
   $$
   f'(z) = -6y^2+6y + 6x^2 + i6x(2y-1) + C = 6(-y^2 +2ixy +x^2) +6(y - ix) + C
   = 6(x+iy)^2 -i6(x+iy) + C = 6z^2 - iz +C.
   $$

That is 
$$
f(z) = 2z^3 - 3iz^2 + Cz + C_1.
$$
To find constant
$$
3-2i = f(0) = C_1,
$$
$$
6-5i = f(1) = 2 -3i +C +3-2i \Rightarrow C = 1. 
$$
Finally 
$$
f(z) = 2z^3 -3iz^2+z + 3-2i.
$$